# How to resize a long table in Latex

Tags: tables

Is there an easy way to resize the table or wrap the text inside the cells?

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{\bf Parameters for training and testing of cGAN networks in various scattering scenarios, using a Google Colaboratory Python environment}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c cc cc c}
\hline
 &&  && SSIM between best model generated and ground truth &&  JI between best model generated and ground truth\\
\cline{7-8} \cline{5-6} 
Scattering Scenario  & No. of image pairs for training & Training time/mins & Model no. selected for testing (out of10) & Mean & Median & Mean & Median & Avg.time for reconstruction/sec(N images)\\
\hline
$  1$ & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx\\
$  2$ & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx\\
$ 3$ & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx\\
$ 4$ & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx\\
$ 5$ & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
  \label{tab:SSIM_comparison}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: note `\bf` has not been defined by default in latex since 1993,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've discovered, the `c` column type does not provide automatic wrapping of cell contents.

To make some progress, I suggest you (a) switch from a `tabular` to a `tabularx` environment and use a centered version of the `X` column type and (b) reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace and omit the whitespace padding that's inserted at both table edges by default, and (c) replace `/` with `\slash` in order to permit line breaking at the `/` ("slash") symbols. Optionally, add the `booktabs` package and replace all instances of `\hline` and `\cline` with `\toprule`/`\midrule`/`\bottomrule` and `\cmidrule`, respectively.

Since your table has 9 [!!] columns, you really ought to think about reducing the amount of text in the header cells. That's a task I can't provide much guidance for, I'm afraid.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page size parameters as needed
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,caption,booktabs}
\captionsetup{font=bf,skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X} % centered version of 'X' column type

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\frenchspacing
\caption{Parameters for training and testing of cGAN networks in various scattering scenarios, using a Google Collaboratory Python environment}
\label{tab:SSIM_comparison}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{9}{C} @{}}
\toprule
 &&&& 
\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep\relax}C}{%
  SSIM between best model generated and ground truth} &  
\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep\relax}C}{%
  JI between best model generated and ground truth} \\
\cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8} 
Scattering Scenario & 
No. of image pairs for training & 
Training time\slash mins & 
Model no. selected for testing (out of 10) & 
Mean & Median & 
Mean & Median & 
Avg. time for reconstruction\slash sec ($N$ images) \\
\midrule
$  1$ & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx\\
$  2$ & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx\\
$  3$ & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx\\
$  4$ & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx\\
$  5$ & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx & xx\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```